# Undefined Variable in View Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

i try to solve this problem and read many post but nothing help me, try to figure out my problem, as i am new to laravel!

this is my Index.blade.view located in `view/posts`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Post</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <?php 
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
        echo "<li><a href = 'post/$post->$id'>".$post->$title."</a></li>";
        }
    ?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

`PostController` :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $posts = Post::all();
        return view('posts.index',compact($posts));
    }

    public function showPost($id){
        $post = Post::find($id);
        return view('posts.post',compact($post));
    }
}
```

i read many post related to this but nothing help me, what i am doing wrong?
this is the problem i am facing : **Undefined variable: posts (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\firstApplication\resources\views\posts\index.blade.php)**

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: @Strom Undefined variable: posts (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\firstApplication\resources\views\posts\index.blade.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change view to

```
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <?php 
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
        echo "<li><a href = 'post/$post->id'>".$post->title."</a></li>";
        }
    ?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Change `$post->$id` to `$post->id` and `$post->$title` to `$post->title`
Also `compact($posts)` to `compact('posts')` and `compact($post)` to `compact('post')`

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have another variable holding data, then your index method should look like:

Access content of $post as `$post->id` instead of `$post->$id`

```
 public function index(){
     $posts = Post::all();
     $someData = []; // extra variable
     return view('posts.index',compact('posts','someData'));
 }
```

Another Change to be made is in view file:
On a side note: you don't have to use traditional PHP tags and foreach, instead you could use Laravel's clean and elegant method like following:

Replace your block of code:

```
<?php 
   foreach ($posts as $post) {
      echo "<li><a href = 'post/$post->$id'>".$post->$title."</a></li>";
   }
?>
```

Updated code:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <li><a href = "{{ url('post/'. $post->id) }}" </a></li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you so much!